# Convert a non hex string to byte C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, byte

I need to convert a non hex string to byte in c#

```
var string1 = "xs";
byte result = byte.parse(string1);
```

But this throws  format exception.
Anything that I am missing.

Comment: Well you're missing some description of what you expect the result to be and why. Note that the code you've given would also fail to compile because C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: How  "xs" should be converted to byte? What output do you expect?

Comment: What do you want to use this for? Please clarify your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
        var string1 = "xs";
        byte[] result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string1);
```

Comment: That will get a byte array rather than a single byte, and the question is far too vague to *assume* that the OP wants the ASCII representation of the string.